# For loop of random walk in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, random-walk

I am currently learning the random walk on Python, I came across the sample code that I couldn't explain please help me to clarify this

My question is that why does x no need to be put in the loop but the code is still able to  operate. The other question is regarding the initial value of the loop `step = random_walk[-1]`.

Thanks!

```
# Numpy is imported, seed is set

# Initialize random_walk

random_walk = [0]

# Complete the ___
for x in range(100) :   # the first question is at here.
    # Set step: last element in random_walk
    step = random_walk[-1] # the other question is at here.
 
    # Roll the dice
    dice = np.random.randint(1,7)

    # Determine next step
    if dice <= 2:
        step = step - 1
    elif dice <= 5:
        step = step + 1
    else:
        step = step + np.random.randint(1,7)

    # append next_step to random_walk
    random_walk.append(step)

# Print random_walk
print(random_walk)
```

Comment: Using the loop variable in the body of the loop is optional. The loop still runs the expected number of times.Usually in such cases you should use `_` as the loop variable.

Comment: `random_walk[-1]` is just the last element of the list `random_walk`. See: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3

Comment: Thank you @rdas for reminding me this basic concept.
Ideally, I should use `for _ in range(100)`?

Comment: Yes. It's the convention.

Comment: Thank you, this really helps me a lot!